# Enable remote screen sharing from headless server on 21.10

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, remote-desktop, vnc, 21.10

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 21.10 that I can SSH in to and doesn't have a video device.

I want to know how to configure it to be able to remote in to the server from my personal machine via VNC or RDP preferably with Gnome Shell or Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: An headless server by definition has no desktop environment.

Comment: Hi @ChanganAuto I think you'll have to expand on that. [Here is an example with setting up Wayland headless using virtual displays](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653672/virtual-wayland-display-server-possible) and [here is an example of setting up Chrome in a lambda](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda).

Comment: Expanding and commenting your links: If you installed Ubuntu Server then it, by default, comes without ANY Desktop Environment (if you need one then you wouldn't be using "server", you'd choose the Ubuntu flavor that comes with your preferred DE). If you want Gnome then you'll have to install Gnome for starters.

Comment: Ok great! If you can turn that in to an answer then I'll be able to accept it.

Comment: Honestly I don't think my previous comment, generic as it is, should be turned into an answer, it wouldn't be proper.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that does definitely work, is to use xRDP. I'm running a few RHEL servers with that configured and enabled (for letting users access powerful and always on machines with various physics software pre-configured).

It lets you connect via any RDP client, giving you a login screen. Multiple users can connect and work simultaneously. The local login is unaffected (however I doubt it is a good idea to simultaneously start gnome on both the local console and remotely).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went for is to install `gnome-session` then to access it remotely setup [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com/).

```
apt install gnome-session
```

Then follow the Chrome Remote Desktop instructions.

Comment: This may end up being the best solution, but I am a bit worried about a third party hosting this and perhaps monitoring what I am doing. Is this a fair thought or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

as you are trying to connect to Ubuntu remotely, even other distro, perhaps ThinLinc would help you to solve the issue. It is heavily based on open source (TigerVNC, noVNC and others) and free for use with limited users. Here they explain how to do use it https://www.cendio.com/thinlinc/docs/install

Comment: Hi Jean. Would I be able to access the ThinLinc server using a standard VNC client?

Comment: Hi @MattCopperwaite, I think this is not possible as it should work with the native clients or the browser based client.